# Selenium Webdriver: Mouse cursor hovering is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Selenium Webdriver: Mouse cursor hovering is not working for firefox version 50**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
public class Ajax_Mouse_Interactions {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
```

**Path for firefox driver**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
"C://Users//user2//Downloads//geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64//geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");        

Thread.sleep(20000);
```

**Actions class for mouse handling**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("nav-link-yourAccount"));

action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
} 
}
```

**Getting following exception**

Upsupported Command Exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this now.
This code works for me.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
...
Point point = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Emitir Guias']")).getLocation();
System.out.println(point.toString());
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(point.x+10,point.y+110); //This 10 and 110 just to adjust coordenate in my case

Thread.sleep(3000); //Pause for you see the mouse move
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12978079/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Gecodriver + Selenium 3.0.1 has issues with `Actions` class.

Refer following links for more details.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/322

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2581

So dvice is to drop back to selenium v2.53.1 and firefox browser 47.0

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
       For selenium webdriverjs 3.6 javascript mouseMove can be used for mouse hover
        const actions = driver.actions({ bridge: true });
        driver.findElement(By.css('#mousehover'))
            .then(function (elem) {
                actions.mouseMove(elem).perform();
                driver.sleep(1000)
                // other actions..
            });`
```